# VBA non centrality parameter for a cumulative distribution function

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to find the cumulative distribution function value at a certain point. I know the TDIST function will do this but there is no function for a CDF with a noncentrality parameter. Is there a way to look up the formula of the TDIST function so I can modify it or is there any way to do this?

Comment: I'm afraid you need to wrtie your own `UDF` for that. Excel seems only concerned with the centered T.

Comment: Shoot. Well, do you have any suggestions on how I can learn to do that? Either a website or code used in the TDIST function?

Comment: The source code of Excel's functions are not published. However, you may try to write a UDF following the equations given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_t-distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function). The UDF is simply a VBA function written in a standard module, something like `Function NonCentralTcdf(v as Double, mu as Double, x as Double) as double`.